# Avoiding multiple MessageCollectors

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with some `messageCollector`. This `messageCollector` is created when the bot detects the `!Hello` command, but if you write again `!Hello`, another `messageCollector` is created.
I checked in the discord.js documentation if it's possible to verify if a collector is already open, but I didn't find it.

I thought to make:

```
if (message === "!Hello") collector.stop("Stopped");
```

But I don't know if it's the right solution.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a variable that contains a boolean and just make it set to true when someone does `!Hello`.

```
let toggled = false;    

if (message === "!Hello" && toggled = true) {
   return;
} else if (message === "!Hello" && toggled = false) {
   toggled = true;
   //run the !Hello code here
}
```

Hope this works, not sure if it's the answer you wanted but this will stop it from creating more `messageCollector`'s.